# /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: Permission denied---Problem while installing Ninja

Tags: c, ubuntu, build

I am install Ninja on Ubuntu (which is running based on windows).

I'm following the following steps:

```
apt-get install re2c
git clone https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git

cd ninja
./configure.py --bootstrap 
cp ./ninja  /usr/bin
```

But there is a problem after type the command at `./configure.py --bootstrap`  that I cannot solve:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: Permission denied
```

I am in root user, and the python 3 is installed.

The permission list:

```
ls -ld configure.py # see the permission

-rwxrwxrwx 1 # the listed permission
```

Has anyone seen this problem?

Comment: The error message seems to be saying you don't have `python`. Try running it with `python3 configure.py --bootstrap` instead?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! @tripleee It works according to what you have mentioned. I was only thinking the permission of running this file but did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved according to @tripleee comment *(thanks)*. Use `python3 configure.py --bootstrap` instead of using `./configure.py --bootstrap` , then it works.